# IoC binding to a resourceful controller method, not constructor

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, ioc-container

Is it possible to bind an instance into a method parameter of a resourceful controller in laravel 4?

Is this even a good idea?  If I have an object that I need for just one method, is it worth it to include it as a constructor parameter?

**app/routes.php**

```
Route::Resource('track', 'TrackController');
```

**app/controller/TrackController.php**

```
class TrackController extends BaseController {
  public function __construct(/Foo/Bar p1, /Foo/Baz p2)
  {
    // All these bindings seem to work
  }

  public function show($id, /Foo/Xyz $xyz)
  {
    // This binding doesn't work, even though the exact same binding
    // in the constructor will work.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic Resolution works only for constructors:

*When a type is not bound in the container, it will use PHP's Reflection facilities to inspect the class and read the **constructor's type-hints**. Using this information, the container can automatically build an instance of the class.*

The best you could do in this case might be:

```
class TrackController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct(/Foo/Bar p1, /Foo/Baz p2, /Foo/Xyz $xyz)
    {
        $this->xyz = $xyz;
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        echo $this->xyz->property;
    }

}
```